# How to apply query on time in mongodb Or Time difference in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, momentjs

my database is like as follows:

```
{
"riderId" : ObjectId("59fac6f760c247118c16539f"),
"pickupDateTime" : ISODate("2017-11-19T07:51:57.491Z"),
"fare" : 15,
"quotes" : [],
"status" : "OPEN",
"closed" : false,
"closeBy" : null
}
```

if i want to fetch data of given pickupDateTime to increase half an hour pickupDateTime n here is my query:

```
db.getCollection('auctions').find( {
pickupDateTime:{
        $gte: new Date(givenTime),
        $lt:  new Date(intervalPickupByTime)
    }
 })
```

but it doesn't work it fetch no records and in node i calculate the half hour difference by using moment as follows:

```
 const intervalPickupByTime = 
 moment(filter.pickupDateTime).add(30, 
 'minutes');
```

I didn't understand why it not works

Comment: Do you use mongoose ?

Comment: yes i use mongoose 4.11.1

Comment: Can you enabled the debug mode and add logs to the OP ? This way : `mongoose.set('debug', true);`